# How do I prevent auto visual mode exit after an action?

Tags: vim, vi

I want to prevent exitting visual mode especially when I have selected a visual block and pasted it somewhere.
An example use case is:
I copy and paste a block of code between two files, but then I want to fix the indentation after pasting. I don't want to reselect the block of code once again and then fix the indentation.

Comment: Why don't indent first properly and copy paste later?

Comment: @dlmeetei even that would still require me to select the block, indent it, and then reselect the block and then yank it. Although I don't plan on doing that since the source-file may need the original indentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you can use `gv` option to "re-select" the previously selected visual block. I actually use the following options to stay in visual mode after indenting a block.

```
vnoremap < < gv
vnoremap > > gv
```

Basically, it is a mapping in **v**isual mode with **no** **re**cursive **map**ing (vnoremap) that maps the `<` command to `< gv`. In other words, it applies `<` and `gv` afterwards. Hence, you can take action and "re-select" the previously selected visual block.

Edit:
And here is another example that maps `Alt+k` and `Alt+j` to move selected visual block up and down, while "re-select"ing the visual block.

```
vnoremap <A-k> :m '<-2<CR>gv=gv
vnoremap <A-j> :m '>+1<CR>gv=gv
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to prevent exitting visual mode

You can't. After executing a command in visual mode you have to leave it for normal mode.

> I don't want to reselect the block of code once again
>
> An example use case is: I copy and paste a block of code

In your case it's a *new block*, so it cannot be "re-selected". So you really have to select it yourself. Use `1v` (or `1vl` if `set selection=exclusive`) to simplify this operation.

Also you can always create a mapping. For example

```
nnoremap <Leader>p pg`[1v
```

Comment: @Kent Well, that's a matter of taste, but `g'` doesn't alter the jumplist, so generally it's a bit more preferable in mappings.

Comment: It would be slightly better to use the output of `visualmode()` rather than simply `v`. But whatever you use will be imperfect here, so maybe not worth the hassle...

Comment: @filbranden Theoretically, `1v` should restore any visual (sub)mode in a right way. But in practice there are some "corner cases" for both `1v`, and `'[' . visualmode() . ']'`, and even for `[`-bookmark itself. As an obvious example, a $-block may become totally unselectable after putting (unless `set ve=block` or `set ve=all`). So, yes, I happened to run into some "issues" myself, and I think that "a reliable re-selection" rather deserves own topic.

Comment: Ah wow indeed! My first impression while testing this was that `1v` was always using char-wise but I was wrong about that... Yeah there are corner cases, but knowing about `1v` is really handy! I'm glad today I learned it exists.